# wkhtmltopdf with javascript-delay not working

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

The pdf that is created using the code below hasn't finished rendering the javascript so javascript was preformed on half of the tables (say if there are 100 tables then sometimes 50 are done, other times 52, 54 etc).

I'm using the flag `--javascript-delay 40000` in trying to delay the retrievement of the page but the results are the same. It's still pulling the trigger too fast. I know this is the issue because when I use the browser everything works correctly.

How can I set the delay properly?  Maybe `shell_exec` is at fault here?

```
$command = shell_exec("xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 640x480x16' wkhtmltopdf-i386 --dpi 300 --javascript-delay 40000 --page
```

**EDIT:**

using the version:

```
wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the problem after searching for hours. **wkhtmltopdf** stops slow scripts:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: A slow script was stopped                                
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
```

So I needed to use the flag `--no-stop-slow-scripts`:

```
$command = shell_exec("xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 640x480x16' wkhtmltopdf-i386 --no-stop-slow-scripts --dpi 300 --page-size A4 $page /tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I was having the same issue!

Comment: Both the `--no-stop-slow-scripts` and the `--javascript-delay 40000` did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @TheMightyLlama. It won't work without the --javascript-delay option.

Comment: @SungKim, I'm glad that even almost three years later this helps.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama and also Tom:  thanks any thanks for the responses, been trying to solve an issue w/ wkhtmltopdf and Twitter tweet embeds for the last 2 days!