# javascript_delay throwing error in wicked_pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, flot, wicked-pdf

Environment:-
Ruby - 1.9.3 ,
Rails - 4.0.0

I am generating pdf using wicked_pdf gem.

For this, I used below code in my controller:-

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
        render :pdf => 'contractors_data',
               :javascript_delay => 5000,
               :disposition => 'attachment',
               :template => 'tiles/templates/pdf/contractors.pdf.erb',
               :header => { :right => 'Page [page] of [topage]' }

end
```

In this pdf, I am generating a graph using `$.plot` method of javascript/jquery.
So **I want to wait pdf generator to wait till `$.plot` not respond and not plot graph over pdf**.

I am sure and confirmed that javascript and jquery are working on this page as I used using wicked_pdf_javascript_link_tag for this.

Now I used `:javascript_delay => 5000` in respond_to format option.
But **it is throwing error** in generating while `:redirect_delay => 5000` are working properly.

I tries this in cmd prompt also. I am getting error on cmd similar to GUI working.

Please answer with good solution.
If possible, please provide code also for reference.

Comment: @Mark : This is the error:-
"Failed to execute: "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --header-right "Page [page] of [topage]" --javascript-delay 500 "file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/wicked_pdf20131018-4048-iz9tz4.html" "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20131018-4048-12zmugm.pdf" Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: Unknown long argument --javascript-delay Name: wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 Synopsis: wkhtmltopdf [OPTIONS]"

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837932/wkhtmltopdf-with-javascript-delay-not-working

Comment: `wicked-pdf` is just a thin wrapper for `wkhtmltopdf`.  That error means that your version of `wkthmtltopdf` does not have the `javascript-delay` option.  Check it's version, it's probably out of date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your version of `wkhtmltopdf` is outdated.  The `javascript-delay` option was introduced in [version 0.10.0](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html).  Here's the [manual for 0.9.9](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html), you'll see no such option.

Comment: thanks Mark...I installed 0.11.0 rc2 version.
It is working now perfectly with some more functionality that I was in need like "table of content" links....:)